# 2 versions of openssl on one server

Tags: redhat, openssl

On a server running RedHat 6.7 with Apache 2.4.37 I proceeded to upgrade OpenSSL to 1.1.0i following the same steps as I've done on other servers with the same set up, but on this one, somehow, 2 versions are installed:

```
openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.0i  14 Aug 2018 (Library: OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017)
```

and that makes the server fail the security scan, as 1.1.0g is the one that appears on the scan and we're required to run 1.1.0i. Both versions were installed from source.

How can I either:

- Configure it to use 1.1.0i
- Remove 1.1.0g completly

or

- Revert the changes

Comment: How did you install OpenSSL, then?

Comment: For installation, I configured as ´sudo ./config no-threads -fPIC shared --prefix=/usr/local/openssl --openssldir=/usr/local/openssl´ld.so.` then add the library to ld.so.conf, export the flags, create symlinks.   I did also updated Apache and configured it to use the newly installed Openssl

Answer (score 1):

The normal way of maintaining multiple versions of a binary, and making it possible to run either of them is to install them in separate locatoions and use symlinks to point whivh one to use ( or a an environment variable, like when installing multiple java versions).

So first figure out which binary you are using:

```
sudo which openssl
```

It might point to /bin/openssl

```
ls -l /bin/openssl
   -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 555296 Apr 11  2018 /bin/openssl
```

Then run ]# /bin/openssl version to see what version it is.

Find which other openssl binaries you have using "locate" or "find" and either replace or symlink the correct version to /bin

or actually /usr/bin, since /bin is a symlink to /user/bin

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Openssl binary in use is on /usr/bin/openssl and for the version command is:  `/usr/bin/openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.0i  14 Aug 2018 (Library: OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017)` That leaves me at the same point where I was, no idea why I get those 2 versions,or ho to point it to use 1.1.0i

Comment: so it boils down to what libraries  it has been linked/compiled with. ldd, objdump, readelf can be used to find more information of whats in use. See also  https://superuser.com/questions/239590/find-libraries-a-binary-was-linked-against